# Can I achieve the below with SQL CTE? Or how can this be achieved?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

This is a dummy customer table.
 I've attached input table
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c1 FROM [Customer]
WHERE country='Germany' 
and Purchasedate is null

SELECT COUNT(*) as c2 FROM [Customer]
WHERE country='Germany' 
and convert(date,Purchasedate) ='2020-04-07'

SELECT COUNT(*) as c3 FROM [Customer]
WHERE country='Germany' 
and convert(date,Purchasedate) ='2020-04-05'

The above code gives 
c1
5
---
c2
3
--
c3
3

But I need a solution where I need all the 3 outputs into a single row
Eg:
c1|c2|c3
5 |3 |3
```

I need this structure as a single dataset as I'm going to use it in my ssrs report.
What sql technique can I use to achieve this? Is there any way that I can use CTE. Pls help me with it.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLb29.png
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data?

Comment: Also mention your SQL Server version

Comment: you don't need a CTE - this is a simple `PIVOT`/ cross tab query

Comment: Providing your current SQL is correct, but the data would be much more useful if it was provided as text instead of an image, so we could use it directly to test a solution. I have voted to reopen the question, but you will get an answer much faster if you also provide the data sample as text, for example using this table generator: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables (you can import a CSV file or provide each cell value manually)

Comment: SELECT sum(case when Purchasedate is null then 1 end) as c1,
       sum(case when convert(date,Purchasedate) = '2020-04-07' then 1 end) as c2,
       sum(case when convert(date,Purchasedate) = '2020-04-05' then 1 end) as c3
FROM [Customer]
WHERE country='Germany'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use case expressions to do this.

```
   SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN code=1 AND month=1 THEN 1 END) as c1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN code=2 AND month=2 THEN 1 END) as c2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN code=3 AND month=3 THEN 1 END) as c3
    FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: This isn't the exact scenario!

Comment: @user9208802 It was already asked to you to include the sample data and the expected output in text format.

Comment: @user9208802 whose fault is that ?. This is the exact scenario that anyone would understand from your question. Fix your question and give some information to make clear what you really want.

Comment: @user9208802 seeing your edited question, this answer was right and returns exactly what you say you are looking for. And only scans one time the table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be a basic solution:

Creating the sample table and populate it with data

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (no INT , code INT , MONTH INT)
GO
INSERT TABLEA Values (1,1,1)
INSERT TABLEA Values (1,1,1)
INSERT TABLEA Values (1,1,1)
INSERT TABLEA Values (1,1,1)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (2,2,2)
INSERT TABLEA Values (3,3,3)
INSERT TABLEA Values (3,3,3)
INSERT TABLEA Values (3,3,3)
INSERT TABLEA Values (3,3,3)
INSERT TABLEA Values (3,3,3)
```

Solution:

```
SELECT (Select count(no)  from TableA
where code=1 and month =1
) AS c1 , (Select count(no)  from TableA
where code=2 and month =2) as c2 ,(Select count(no)  from TableA
where code=3 and month =3) as c3

+----+----+----+
| c1 | c2 | c3 |
+----+----+----+
|  4 |  6 |  5 |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I don't want to check my table many times! I want it to be in a temp table or something else! Cause my table is huge!

Comment: @user9208802 You want a dynamic pivot then. You MUST be clearer about your requirements. We are solving this repeatedly and you are moving the goal posts as solutions come in. Please also consider not using exclamation points to your sentences it comes off as rude and demanding. We are volunteering our time and knowledge to help you and you will find that help dry up very quickly.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. I'll be clear with my requirements.

Comment: @JNevill. Can you please check the question now.